# Best way to handle multi-thread cleanup

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a server-type application, and I have an issue with making sure thread's aren't deleted before they complete. The code below pretty much represents my server; the cleanup is required to prevent a build up of dead threads in the list.

```
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void doSomethingThreaded(function<void()> cleanupFunction, function<bool()> getStopFlag) {
       somethingThread = thread([cleanupFunction, getStopFlag, this]() {
          doSomething(getStopFlag);
          cleanupFunction();
       });

    }
private:
    void doSomething(function<bool()> getStopFlag);
    thread somethingThread;
    ...
}

class B {
public:
    void runServer();

    void stop() {
        stopFlag = true;
        waitForListToBeEmpty();
    }
private:
    void waitForListToBeEmpty() { ... };
    void handleAccept(...) {
        shared_ptr<A> newClient(new A());
        { 
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(listMutex);
            clientData.push_back(newClient);
        }
        newClient.doSomethingThreaded(bind(&B::cleanup, this, newClient), [this]() {
            return stopFlag;
        });
    }

    void cleanup(shared_ptr<A> data) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(listMutex);
        clientData.remove(data);
    }

    list<shared_ptr<A>> clientData;
    mutex listMutex;
    atomc<bool> stopFlag;
}
```

The issue seems to be that the destructors run in the wrong order - i.e. the shared_ptr is destructed at when the thread's function completes, meaning the 'A' object is deleted before thread completion, causing havok when the thread's destructor is called.

i.e.
Call cleanup function
All references to this (i.e. an A object) removed, so call destructor (including this thread's destructor)
Call this thread's destructor again -- OH NOES!

I've looked at alternatives, such as maintaining a 'to be removed' list which is periodically used to clean the primary list by another thread, or using a time-delayed deletor function for the shared pointers, but both of these seem abit chunky and could have race conditions.

Anyone know of a good way to do this? I can't see an easy way of refactoring it to work ok.

Answer (score 3):

Are the threads joinable or detached?  I don't see any `detach`,
which means that destructing the thread object without having
joined it is a fatal error.  You might try simply detaching it,
although this can make a clean shutdown somewhat complex.  (Of
course, for a lot of servers, there should never be a shutdown
anyway.)  Otherwise: what I've done in the past is to create
a reaper thread; a thread which does nothing but join any
outstanding threads, to clean up after them.

I might add that this is a good example of a case where
shared_ptr is *not* appropriate.  You want full control over
when the delete occurs; if you detach, you can do it in the
clean up function (but quite frankly, just using `delete this;`
at the end of the lambda in `A::doSomethingThreaded` seems more
readable); otherwise, you do it after you've joined, in the
reaper thread.

EDIT:

For the reaper thread, something like the following should work:

```
class ReaperQueue
{
    std::deque<A*> myQueue;
    std::mutex myMutex;
    std::conditional_variable myCond;
    A* getOne()
    {
        std::lock<std::mutex> lock( myMutex );
        myCond.wait( lock, [&]( !myQueue.empty() ) );
        A* results = myQueue.front();
        myQueue.pop_front();
        return results;
    }
public:
    void readyToReap( A* finished_thread )
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock( myMutex );
        myQueue.push_back( finished_thread );
        myCond.notify_all();
    }

    void reaperThread()
    {
        for ( ; ; )
        {
            A* mine = getOne();
            mine->somethingThread.join();
            delete mine;
        }
    }
};
```

(Warning: I've not tested this, and I've tried to use the C++11
functionality.  I've only actually implemented it, in the past,
using pthreads, so there could be some errors.  The basic
principles should hold, however.)

To use, create an instance, then start a thread calling
`reaperThread` on it.  In the cleanup of each thread, call
`readyToReap`.

To support a clean shutdown, you may want to use two queues: you
insert each thread into the first, as it is created, and then
move it from the first to the second (which would correspond to
`myQueue`, above) in `readyToReap`.  To shut down, you then wait
until both queues are empty (not starting any new threads in
this interval, of course).

Comment: can you provide some example?

Comment: @lizusek An example for what?  I suggested several different solutions.

Comment: an example of how to create a reaper thread; a thread which does nothing but join any outstanding threads, to clean up after them.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that, since you manage `A` via shared pointers, the `this` pointer captured by the thread lambda really needs to be a shared pointer rather than a raw pointer to prevent it from becoming dangling.  The problem is that there's no easy way to create a shared_ptr from a raw pointer when you don't have an actual shared_ptr as well.

One way to get around this is to use `shared_from_this`:

```
class A : public enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    void doSomethingThreaded(function<void()> cleanupFunction, function<bool()> getStopFlag) {
       somethingThread = thread([cleanupFunction, getStopFlag, this]() {
          shared_ptr<A> temp = shared_from_this();
          doSomething(getStopFlag);
          cleanupFunction();
       });
```

this creates an extra shared_ptr to the `A` object that keeps it alive until the thread finishes.

Note that you still have the problem with `join`/`detach` that James Kanze identified -- *Every* thread *must* have either `join` or `detach` called on it exactly once before it is destroyed.  You can fulfill that requirement by adding a `detach` call to the thread lambda if you never care about the thread exit value.

You also have potential for problems if `doSomethingThreaded` is called multiple times on a single `A` object...

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I took abit of both answers given (i.e. James' detach suggestion, and Chris' suggestion about shared_ptr's).

My resultant code looks like this and seems neater and doesn't cause a crash on shutdown or client disconnect:

using namespace std;

```
class A {
public:
    void doSomething(function<bool()> getStopFlag) {
        ...
    }
private:
    ...
}

class B {
public:
    void runServer();

    void stop() {
        stopFlag = true;
        waitForListToBeEmpty();
    }
private:
    void waitForListToBeEmpty() { ... };
    void handleAccept(...) {
        shared_ptr<A> newClient(new A());
        { 
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(listMutex);
            clientData.push_back(newClient);
        }
        thread clientThread([this, newClient]() { 
            // Capture the shared_ptr until thread over and done with.

            newClient->doSomething([this]() {
                return stopFlag;
            });
            cleanup(newClient);
        });
        // Detach to remove the need to store these threads until their completion.
        clientThread.detach();
    }

    void cleanup(shared_ptr<A> data) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(listMutex);
        clientData.remove(data);
    }

    list<shared_ptr<A>> clientData; // Can remove this if you don't 
                                    // need to connect with your clients.
                                    // However, you'd need to make sure this 
                                    // didn't get deallocated before all clients 
                                    // finished as they reference the boolean stopFlag
                                    // OR make it a shared_ptr to an atomic boolean
    mutex listMutex;
    atomc<bool> stopFlag;
}
```